# Encontrar caractere sucedido por outro caractere usando RegEx

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regex

Estou tentando montar uma expressão regular que consegue identificar e corrigir um JSON inválido. O que estou tentando fazer especificamente é o seguinte, usando como exemplo o seguinte JSON:

```js
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123",
        "anotherObject": {
            "name": "something"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland",
            "anotherArray": [
                [3, 3]
                [3, 3]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

No caso a chave `anotherArray` é inválida já que está faltando uma `,` entre o primeiro e o segundo array. Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma regex que consiga identificar quando um `]` é sucedido por um `[` e acrescentar uma vírgula no meio usando `re.sub()`, para que o resultado final seja este:

```js
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123",
        "anotherObject": {
            "name": "something"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland",
            "anotherArray": [
                [3, 3],
                [3, 3]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

O máximo que consegui fazer foi `(?<=])` mas ele encontra todos os fecha colchetes, não só os que são sucedidos por abre colchetes.

Comment: Usar um único regex e da forma que esta como foi descrito na resposta aceita me parece um erro. Se você eventualmente tiver um JSON assim, **"mesmo que valido"**, `"street": "[foo] [bar]"` isto vai falhar, pois a regex vai causar algo como: `"street": "[foo], [bar]"`, o que mudaria a string de qualquer forma e claro para você pode até parecer pouca coisa, mas é apenas um exemplo, algo assim pode causar bem mais coisas que você não poderá prever Para resolver isto provavelmente precisaria criar o seu proprio "parse", aonde você identificaria "strings" e "chaves", [...]

Comment: [...] mas lhe adianto, não será fácil, terá que fazer bem mais que uma regex e também precisará colocar muita lógica para o script saber como agir em possíveis situações, um exemplo de onde passei por problema semelhante é que em meu framework PHP eu crie um seletor para DOM estilo do CSS, quando me deparo com um seletor assim `[foo="abc[def]"]` por causa dos `[` e `]` falhava, então tive pegar tudo isolar e destrinchar para que o que estivesse dentro de `[]` fosse resolvido primeiro e depois resolveria o final. Outros seletores PHP como phpquery falham, pois o dev não previu tais problemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possível até é, só não sei se vale a pena. Dependendo do quão variados são os seus dados, fazer uma regex que contemple todos os casos pode ficar complicado demais. O ideal é corrigir os dados na origem, para que sempre gere um JSON correto.

Dito isso, **para este caso específico**, daria para fazer algo assim:

```
invalido = """
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123",
        "anotherObject": {
            "name": "something"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland",
            "anotherArray": [
                [3, 3]
                [3, 3]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
"""

import re

valido = re.sub(r'\][^,]+\[', r'], [', invalido)

import json

dados = json.loads(valido)
```

A ideia da regex é pegar um `]`, seguido de `[^,]+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam vírgula), seguido de `[`.

Na substituição, eu troco tudo isso por `], [` (coloco uma vírgula entre eles).

Isso resolve para este caso, mas se o JSON tiver por exemplo:

```
{ "chave": "[valor1]  [valor2]" }
```

A regex não consegue detectar que o trecho `]  [` faz parte de uma string e não deve ser substituído. E para detectar esses casos, ela começa a ficar complicada demais e talvez não valha a pena.

Como já dito, o ideal é corrigir isso na origem (quem gera o JSON deve garantir que é válido, quem lê não deveria se preocupar em arrumar essas coisas).

Comment: Boa! eu só preferia manter: `re.sub(r'\]([^,]+)\[',  r'],\1 [', invalido)`

Answer (score 6):

A resposta está sendo publicada apenas com a finalidade de compartilhar conhecimento sobre a exceção lançada e seus campos e não é recomendado aplicar o código aqui presente em produção. **A solução definitiva e segura será sempre corrigir na fonte do problema onde é gerado o JSON**.

Para contornar **única e exclusivamente** a falta de vírgulas no JSON, você pode verificar qual é a exceção lançada por `json.loads` analisando a mensagem de erro.

Quando o JSON é inválido, a exceção `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` é lançada e ela possui algumas informações que podem ser úteis dependendo do contexto. O campo `msg` possui a mensagem de erro lançada; o campo `doc` possui o próprio JSON analisado e o campo `pos` possui a posição no JSON que ocorreu o erro. Como iremos tratar apenas a ausência da vírgula podemos fazer uma chamada recursiva adicionando a vírgula faltante no JSON.

```
def json_loads_with_missing_commas(data):
    try:
        return json.loads(data)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as error:
        if error.msg == "Expecting ',' delimiter":
            # Cria um novo JSON adicionando a vírgula onde deu erro
            data = error.doc[:error.pos] + ',' + error.doc[error.pos:]
            return json_loads_with_missing_commas(data)
        raise error
```

Para o JSON de exemplo, ao remover todas as vírgulas teríamos:

```
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123"
        "anotherObject": {
            "name": "something"
        }
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland"
            "anotherArray": [
                [3 3]
                [3 3]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Ao fazer `json_loads_with_missing_commas(data)` para analisar o JSON acima teríamos a saída:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "anotherObject": {
                "name": "something"
            },
            "address": {
                "street": "Dreamland",
                "anotherArray": [
                    [
                        3,
                        3
                    ],
                    [
                        3,
                        3
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/UnlawfulOutstandingEngineer)</sup>

Qualquer outro erro no JSON seria propagado sem alterações.

Comment: Não testei, mas parece ser isto mesmo o ideal. Parabéns, isso é uma solução pensada nos problemas. Assim que testar com calma vou lançar uma recompensa. PS: o começo da resposta de qualquer forma já define a resolução, pessoalmente eu teria criticado o uso indiscriminado do regex, mas creio que ficou implícito.

Comment: Excelente estratégia!

Answer (score 2):

Aqui vai uma solução que não modifica a estrutura do JSON original (caso você queira salvá-lo de volta para um arquivo com a mesma "cara", por exemplo):

```
string = """
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123",
        "anotherObject": {
            "name": "something"
        },
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland",
            "anotherArray": [
                [3, 3]
                [3, 3]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
"""

import re
import json

pattern = re.compile(r'\][^,]+\[')
for match in re.findall(pattern, string):
    sub = match.replace(']', '],')
    string = string.replace(match, sub)

json.loads(string)  # não dá erro
```

O regex procura por um caractere `]`, seguido de quaisquer caracteres exceto vírgulas até o próximo caractere `[`.

Então, no loop é feita a substituição de `]` por `],` para cada match encontrado no seu arquivo.

Se você printar o string após o loop, vai ver que a estrutura de espaçamento e linhas continua a mesma, apenas com a substituição feita.

Testei apenas com seu exemplo, mas acredito que a estrutura deve ser mantida em diferentes casos, exceto no caso de have mais de um `]` antes do `[` (embora nesse caso o arquivo tem problemas de formatação ainda maiores...)

Answer (score 1):

Como dito:

- 1: tentar corrigir na fonte
- 2: tentar corrigir usando try json.loads

Usando estritamente expressões regulares eu tentaria marcar APENAS as ocorrências de "] espaços [" mantendo a formatação, não retirando nada:

```
j = re.sub(r'\](\s*)\[',  r']FIXME\1[', j)
```

e estudava se houve surpresas... E se não houver ocorrencias em sítos
imprevistos, substituir FIXME por ","

```
j = re.sub(r'\](\s*)\[',  r'],\1[', j)
```

Embora não seja o caminho ideal, em muitos casos este tipo de soluções são úteis.

Como referido há contextos onde a vírgula não deveria ser inserida.
É fácil tratar do caso das strings "[ ], [ ]", mas há mais casos...